# How to animate width of view with initial width 0dp with AnimatorSet?

Tags: android-animation

I'm trying to animate the width of view with initial width `0dp` with AnimatorSet using xml. I've tried using `<objectAnimator />` with `"scaleX"`, but unsurprisingly, that didn't work since 0 x 8 is just 0.

I've tried looking online, including on here, but could find an example with xml. The Android official documentation suggests

```
<animator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="width"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="8"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

should work, but when I run the animation, nothing happens. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you a solution using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) with which you only need one line of code to do it :

```
yourView.animate().scaleX(8).setDuration(1000);
```

I suggest you use ViewPropertyAnimator for all kinds of animations, instead of AnimatorSet, as it is very easy and concise. From experience, I have found the AnimatorSet to be buggy in some cases in the past.